# Do I need to synchronize ExecutorService.execute()?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, threadpoolexecutor

I have created a Enum singleton as below:

```
public enum Logging {

    INSTANCE;   
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
}
```

Now I am using this pool for logging asynchronously in specific cases.
Calling code is like below:

```
Logging.INSTANCE.execute(new MyRunnable("LogType.A",logData));
```

Run method of the MyRunnable object is simple like below:

```
    public class MyRunnable {
        public MyRunnable(LogType logType,String logData){
           this.logType=logType;
           this.logData=logData;
        }  
        public void run() {
                switch(logType) {
                case A:         
                    logData(Logger.getLogger(A_LOG),logData);
                    break;
                case B:         
                    logData(Logger.getLogger(B_LOG,logData));
                    break;
        }

        private void logData (Logger logger,String logdata) {
        if(some condition)
         logger.info(logdata);
        else
         do something else;
        }
    }
```

Now my query is will I face any concurrency issues if I am submitting lot of requests to the queue with multiple threads ?Isn't executor.execute(task) already synchronized or Do I need to wrap execute method in the synchronized method(in Logging enum) and than call that method like below:

```
public synchronized  void submitTask(Runnable task) {       
    executor.execute(task);     
}
```

Comment: hmmm... could it be the snippets are from different versions of your code? You will run into concurrency issues if `logData()` or `logSData()` are not thread-safe. But then using a thread pool wouldn't make any sense at all.

Comment: Your `executor` should be `final`; at the moment, nothing prevents an external method to set it to `null`!

Comment: @fge thanks for pointing out the final thing.

Comment: @Axel I have updated the question with logData method.It just logs into the corresponding logFile.Do you still think there is going to be a concurrency issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now my query is will I face any concurrency issues if I am submitting
>   lot of requests to the queue with multiple threads ?

**No** there is no need of using synchronized.

```
public synchronized  void submitTask(Runnable task) {       
    executor.execute(task);     
}
```

Even here it is safe to remove synchronized.

```
public enum Logger {
    INSTANCE;   

   ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

   public void log(String logType, String logData){
       //you internally create a instance of your runnable and not leave on caller to create instance

      pool.execute(new MyRunnable(logType, logData));
   }
}
```